# only return results if they are different, rxjs Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, rxjs5

I'm building a component that has a material datagrid

Within each row I'm creating a component dynamically and adding to the last cell, it's set up as an ellipsis (a view more button)

I have a function that adds them to the table cell and adds information to them from data returned from an api call

```
  addEllipsisToTable() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      let sideMenu = this.sideMenu.toArray()
      // Add ellipsis menus' to returned results
      for (let i = 0; i < sideMenu.length; i++) {
        const factory = this.resolver.resolveComponentFactory(this.ellipsis);
        let container = this.sideMenu.toArray()[i]
        const ellipsisComponent = container.createComponent(factory);
        ellipsisComponent.instance.data = this.returnedData[i]
      }
    }, 300)

  }
```

This works, however when I filter the records using a search field, some times the ellipsis is added twice.

This is the code for the search:

```
let txt: Filter;
    fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup')
      .pipe(
        debounceTime(200),
        distinctUntilChanged(),
        tap(() => {
          this.filtersArray = [];
          txt = {
            Value: this.input.nativeElement.value,
            Operation: 5,
            Property: 'Name'
          }
          this.filtersArray.push(txt);
        })
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.paginator.pageIndex = 0;
        this.loadUserPage();//reloads datagrid
      });
```

As you type and data is returned, the getPagedInfo function gets executed, which removes the ellipsis, gets the data and then adds new ones back in:

```
getPagedInfo() {
    return this.dataSource.pagedInfoSubject
      // .skip(1)
      .pipe(
        tap(() => this.removeEllipsisFromTable())
      )
      .subscribe((data) => {
        this.selection.clear();
        this.totalItems = data.totalItems;
        this.returnedData = data.returnedData;
        this.addEllipsisToTable()//This sometimes gets performed twice
        console.log(this.returnedData)
        //returnedData holds array of current visible items
        if (this.totalItems == 0) {
          this.filtersArray = [];
        } else if (this.totalItems < 10) {
          this.filtersArray = [];
        }
      });
  }
```

Is there an rxjs function I can use maybe, or am I going to have to match new returned data with old and if different, then add?

Comment: Can you replace your `.skip(1)` with `take(1)`? If `addEllipsisToTable` gets called multiple times, that can only mean your Observable returns multiple times.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, tried your suggestion, had to use .skip(1).take(1), as when the app first loads it seems to load undefined results first, so if I used just .take(1) it didn't load, the thing is take() unsubscribes, so this function does not fire again, and I need it to